# Testing (C1+C3) on Cypress 3.0.3 throws error on QRDA 1 which are available for QRDA 3

Tags: jira, mirth, c-cda

**Note :** Please some one please create a new Tag for QRDA

I'm stuck in a confused situation. I'm performing QRDA 1 and QRDA 3 test on Cypress 3.0.3 and came across the following issue.

```
Calculated value (0.0) for DENOM (BF63669B-FF4B-47E9-94DA-50F923F374CF) does not match expected value (1.0)

Calculated value (0.0) for IPP (D88D0F2F-3176-44D8-99CE-63145C8BABB6) does not match expected value (1.0)
```

The above two errors looks like an reporting error on QRDA-3. But it happens while passing QRDA 1 files. The QRDA-3 passed successfully for C3 testing. There is no error for this measure CMS26 on QRDA3.

I checked for QRDA 1 structural issues, it matches perfectly with the expected files of cypress of QRDA 1. No template Id mismatches or anything.

The ID's provided in this issues are also available for on QRDA 3. I'm just running out of clues to identify these issues. It would be really great if I get an Idea where the issue will be.

Posted in JIRA too. please check : https://oncprojectracking.healthit.gov/support/projects/CYPRESS/issues/CYPRESS-899

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I happen to post this problem in the JIRA to get a clarity.

It seems like, it is the issue with the date binding. But, though there is a structure issue, when we go for C1 testing for QRDA-1 Cypress has good possibility to still show it as Reporting error or Submission error.

For QRDA-3, it's a different scenario. When there is a Reporting error, then the binding value is wrong.

Link :
https://oncprojectracking.healthit.gov/support/browse/CYPRESS-898